# What is a correct alternative for word-characters including unicode ones too?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

It turned out that the `\w` character class which works like a charm in for example in .NET `C#`, doesn't work in `Javascript`. Or more proper to say that it doesn't treat Unicode characters as word-characters, hence breaking a lot of things.

I've found some articles and posts about `Javascript` not supporting Unicode in regular expressions, however I couldn't find any alternative solutions or workarounds.

How could I substitute the `\w` in a regex so that it would still work as expected, also including Unicode characters in Javascript as well?

Comment: [you'll just have to select the various unicode ranges represented by `\w` in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable word class **\w+** regex would be (As defined by C#)
`[\p{General_Category=Connector_Punctuation}\p{General_Category_Mask=Decimal_Number}\p{General_Category_Mask=Mark}\p{General_Category_Mask=Modifier_Letter}\p{General_Category_Mask=Other_Letter}\p{General_Category_Mask=Titlecase_Letter}\p{General_Category_Mask=Lowercase_Letter}\p{General_Category_Mask=Uppercase_Letter}]+`

Testing this on the range U+000000 - U+10FFFF in Unicode 9,
and converting it to UTF-16 ranges (using *\uXXXX* syntax)
yields a much slower and large regex that matches the same as the regex above.

```
 (?:
      [\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u005F\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1-\u05C2\u05C4-\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E8\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u08D4-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7-\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47-\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47-\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56-\u0B57\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82-\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C00-\u0C03\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55-\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5-\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D01-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D57\u0D5F-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82-\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0DF2-\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB9\u0EBB-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18-\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772-\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC-\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180D\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1AB0-\u1ABE\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CF6\u1CF8-\u1CF9\u1D00-\u1DF5\u1DFB-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u203F-\u2040\u2054\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183-\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u2E2F\u3005-\u3006\u302A-\u302F\u3031-\u3035\u303B-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA672\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA6E5\uA6F0-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C5\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABEA\uABEC-\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\uFE33-\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]
   |  
      (?:
           \uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDDFD\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDEE0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF40\uDF42-\uDF49\uDF50-\uDF7A\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF]
        |  \uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]
        |  \uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37-\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4-\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE-\uDDBF\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE06\uDE0C-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE3F\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE6\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]
        |  \uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]
        |  \uD804[\uDC00-\uDC46\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC7F-\uDCBA\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD00-\uDD34\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD73\uDD76\uDD80-\uDDC4\uDDCA-\uDDCC\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE37\uDE3E\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEEA\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF00-\uDF03\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F-\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32-\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3C-\uDF44\uDF47-\uDF48\uDF4B-\uDF4D\uDF50\uDF57\uDF5D-\uDF63\uDF66-\uDF6C\uDF70-\uDF74]
        |  \uD805[\uDC00-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDB5\uDDB8-\uDDC0\uDDD8-\uDDDD\uDE00-\uDE40\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEB7\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF1D-\uDF2B\uDF30-\uDF39]
        |  \uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]
        |  \uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC36\uDC38-\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F\uDC92-\uDCA7\uDCA9-\uDCB6]
        |  \uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]
        |  \uD809[\uDC80-\uDD43]
        |  \uD80C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]
        |  \uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]
        |  \uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDEF0-\uDEF4\uDF00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]
        |  \uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50-\uDF7E\uDF8F-\uDF9F\uDFE0]
        |  [\uD81C-\uD820][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD821[\uDC00-\uDFEC]
        |  \uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]
        |  \uD82C[\uDC00-\uDC01]
        |  \uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99\uDC9D-\uDC9E]
        |  \uD834[\uDD65-\uDD69\uDD6D-\uDD72\uDD7B-\uDD82\uDD85-\uDD8B\uDDAA-\uDDAD\uDE42-\uDE44]
        |  \uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E-\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5-\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD836[\uDE00-\uDE36\uDE3B-\uDE6C\uDE75\uDE84\uDE9B-\uDE9F\uDEA1-\uDEAF]
        |  \uD838[\uDC00-\uDC06\uDC08-\uDC18\uDC1B-\uDC21\uDC23-\uDC24\uDC26-\uDC2A]
        |  \uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDCD0-\uDCD6\uDD00-\uDD4A\uDD50-\uDD59]
        |  \uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21-\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51-\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61-\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]
        |  [\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]
        |  [\uD86A-\uD86C][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]
        |  [\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]
        |  \uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]
        |  \uDB40[\uDD00-\uDDEF]
      )
 )+
```

As defined by [TRS18 word](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#word) (which has a typo)
The property regex is
`[\p{Alphabetic=Yes}\p{General_Category_Mask=Mark}\p{General_Category=Decimal_Number}\p{General_Category=Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control=Yes}]+`

Where the *complete* conversion to UTF-16 using ICU UCD (now part of Unicode.org writ-large) is only slightly smaller, but complete..

```
 (?:
      [\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u005F\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1-\u05C2\u05C4-\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E8\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u08D4-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7-\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47-\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47-\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56-\u0B57\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82-\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C00-\u0C03\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55-\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5-\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D01-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D57\u0D5F-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82-\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0DF2-\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB9\u0EBB-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18-\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772-\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC-\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180D\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1AB0-\u1ABE\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CF6\u1CF8-\u1CF9\u1D00-\u1DF5\u1DFB-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u200C-\u200D\u203F-\u2040\u2054\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u24B6-\u24E9\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u2E2F\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u302F\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA672\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C5\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABEA\uABEC-\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\uFE33-\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]
   |  
      (?:
           \uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDD40-\uDD74\uDDFD\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDEE0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF4A\uDF50-\uDF7A\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF\uDFD1-\uDFD5]
        |  \uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]
        |  \uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37-\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4-\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE-\uDDBF\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE06\uDE0C-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE3F\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE6\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]
        |  \uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]
        |  \uD804[\uDC00-\uDC46\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC7F-\uDCBA\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD00-\uDD34\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD73\uDD76\uDD80-\uDDC4\uDDCA-\uDDCC\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE37\uDE3E\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEEA\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF00-\uDF03\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F-\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32-\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3C-\uDF44\uDF47-\uDF48\uDF4B-\uDF4D\uDF50\uDF57\uDF5D-\uDF63\uDF66-\uDF6C\uDF70-\uDF74]
        |  \uD805[\uDC00-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDB5\uDDB8-\uDDC0\uDDD8-\uDDDD\uDE00-\uDE40\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEB7\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF1D-\uDF2B\uDF30-\uDF39]
        |  \uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]
        |  \uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC36\uDC38-\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F\uDC92-\uDCA7\uDCA9-\uDCB6]
        |  \uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]
        |  \uD809[\uDC00-\uDC6E\uDC80-\uDD43]
        |  \uD80C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]
        |  \uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]
        |  \uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDEF0-\uDEF4\uDF00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]
        |  \uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50-\uDF7E\uDF8F-\uDF9F\uDFE0]
        |  [\uD81C-\uD820][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD821[\uDC00-\uDFEC]
        |  \uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]
        |  \uD82C[\uDC00-\uDC01]
        |  \uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99\uDC9D-\uDC9E]
        |  \uD834[\uDD65-\uDD69\uDD6D-\uDD72\uDD7B-\uDD82\uDD85-\uDD8B\uDDAA-\uDDAD\uDE42-\uDE44]
        |  \uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E-\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5-\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD836[\uDE00-\uDE36\uDE3B-\uDE6C\uDE75\uDE84\uDE9B-\uDE9F\uDEA1-\uDEAF]
        |  \uD838[\uDC00-\uDC06\uDC08-\uDC18\uDC1B-\uDC21\uDC23-\uDC24\uDC26-\uDC2A]
        |  \uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDCD0-\uDCD6\uDD00-\uDD4A\uDD50-\uDD59]
        |  \uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21-\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51-\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61-\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]
        |  \uD83C[\uDD30-\uDD49\uDD50-\uDD69\uDD70-\uDD89]
        |  [\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]
        |  [\uD86A-\uD86C][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]
        |  [\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]
        |  \uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]
        |  \uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]
        |  \uDB40[\uDD00-\uDDEF]
      )
 )+
```

Compressed it's

```
(?:[\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u005F\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1-\u05C2\u05C4-\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E8\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u08D4-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7-\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47-\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47-\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56-\u0B57\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82-\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C00-\u0C03\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55-\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5-\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D01-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D57\u0D5F-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82-\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0DF2-\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB9\u0EBB-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18-\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772-\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC-\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180D\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1AB0-\u1ABE\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CF6\u1CF8-\u1CF9\u1D00-\u1DF5\u1DFB-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u200C-\u200D\u203F-\u2040\u2054\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u24B6-\u24E9\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u2E2F\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u302F\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA672\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C5\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABEA\uABEC-\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\uFE33-\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|(?:\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDD40-\uDD74\uDDFD\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDEE0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF4A\uDF50-\uDF7A\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF\uDFD1-\uDFD5]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37-\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4-\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE-\uDDBF\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE06\uDE0C-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE3F\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE6\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]|\uD804[\uDC00-\uDC46\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC7F-\uDCBA\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD00-\uDD34\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD73\uDD76\uDD80-\uDDC4\uDDCA-\uDDCC\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE37\uDE3E\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEEA\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF00-\uDF03\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F-\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32-\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3C-\uDF44\uDF47-\uDF48\uDF4B-\uDF4D\uDF50\uDF57\uDF5D-\uDF63\uDF66-\uDF6C\uDF70-\uDF74]|\uD805[\uDC00-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDB5\uDDB8-\uDDC0\uDDD8-\uDDDD\uDE00-\uDE40\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEB7\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF1D-\uDF2B\uDF30-\uDF39]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC36\uDC38-\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F\uDC92-\uDCA7\uDCA9-\uDCB6]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]|\uD809[\uDC00-\uDC6E\uDC80-\uDD43]|\uD80C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDEF0-\uDEF4\uDF00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50-\uDF7E\uDF8F-\uDF9F\uDFE0]|[\uD81C-\uD820][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD821[\uDC00-\uDFEC]|\uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]|\uD82C[\uDC00-\uDC01]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99\uDC9D-\uDC9E]|\uD834[\uDD65-\uDD69\uDD6D-\uDD72\uDD7B-\uDD82\uDD85-\uDD8B\uDDAA-\uDDAD\uDE42-\uDE44]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E-\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5-\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]|\uD836[\uDE00-\uDE36\uDE3B-\uDE6C\uDE75\uDE84\uDE9B-\uDE9F\uDEA1-\uDEAF]|\uD838[\uDC00-\uDC06\uDC08-\uDC18\uDC1B-\uDC21\uDC23-\uDC24\uDC26-\uDC2A]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDCD0-\uDCD6\uDD00-\uDD4A\uDD50-\uDD59]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21-\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51-\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61-\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|\uD83C[\uDD30-\uDD49\uDD50-\uDD69\uDD70-\uDD89]|[\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|[\uD86A-\uD86C][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|[\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]|\uDB40[\uDD00-\uDDEF]))
```

Generated by [RegexFormat 8](http://www.regexformat.com) using the UCD interface

Comment: UTS18 defines what a Unicode-aware `\w` should match. Why make up your own set of properties instead of using those?

Comment: @MathiasBynens - Yeah, UTS18 states `\w, then it would use the approximation above instead` meaning their definition is unsettled and an approximation. I'll give the conversion, but it's not made up buddy. Alphabetic alone is 118,000 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it turned out that I have very limited knowledge in this area. I don't know if it's worth implementing it though. Maybe I'll just stick with backend-only validation in these situations, and perhaps substitute \w with a simplified black-list at frontend.

Comment: No problem. It's actually not as slow as you think. If you have a text made up of %95 ascii, it's almost as fast as JS `\w`. The reason, if you'll notice is that ranges in character classes are probably in a low to high range order in the resultant state machine. In these generated conversion classes, the lower codepoints come first, meaning it will probably find them first, then quit looking if the character is beyond the range or not found within a max range. If a lot of Unicode exists, maybe the reverse is true in that it has to check all the lower ranges.

Answer (score 2):

[UTS18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#word) defines the Unicode properties that should be used to match word characters.

To quote [***Unicode property escapes in JavaScript regular expressions***](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes):

> To match any word symbol in Unicode rather than just ASCII `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, use `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]` per UTS18.

That would look like:

```
/([\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]+)/gu
```

JavaScript doesn’t support `\p` in regular expressions yet (see the link for more information on that proposal). Meanwhile, you can use [the transpiled version](https://mothereff.in/regexpu#input=const+regex+%3D+%2F%28%5B%5Cp%7BAlphabetic%7D%5Cp%7BMark%7D%5Cp%7BDecimal_Number%7D%5Cp%7BConnector_Punctuation%7D%5Cp%7BJoin_Control%7D%5D%2B%29%2Fgu%3B%0Aconst+text+%3D+%60%0AAmharic%3A+%E1%8B%A8%E1%8A%94+%E1%88%9B%E1%8A%95%E1%8B%A3%E1%89%A0%E1%89%A2%E1%8B%AB+%E1%88%98%E1%8A%AA%E1%8A%93+%E1%89%A0%E1%8B%93%E1%88%A3%E1%8B%8E%E1%89%BD+%E1%89%B0%E1%88%9E%E1%88%8D%E1%89%B7%E1%88%8D%0ABengali%3A+%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0+%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AB%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%9F+%E0%A6%95%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%81%E0%A6%9A%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%9B-%E0%A6%8F+%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE+%E0%A6%B9%E0%A7%9F%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%9B%E0%A7%87%0AGeorgian%3A+%E1%83%A9%E1%83%94%E1%83%9B%E1%83%98+%E1%83%AE%E1%83%9D%E1%83%9B%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%93%E1%83%98+%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%B0%E1%83%90%E1%83%94%E1%83%A0%E1%83%9D+%E1%83%91%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98%E1%83%A8%E1%83%96%E1%83%94+%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%95%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%90+%E1%83%92%E1%83%95%E1%83%94%E1%83%9A%E1%83%97%E1%83%94%E1%83%95%E1%83%96%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98%E1%83%97%0AMacedonian%3A+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BE+%D1%98%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%0AVietnamese%3A+T%C3%A0u+c%C3%A1nh+ng%E1%BA%A7m+c%E1%BB%A7a+t%C3%B4i+%C4%91%E1%BA%A7y+l%C6%B0%C6%A1n%0A%60%3B%0A%0Alet+match%3B%0Awhile+%28match+%3D+regex.exec%28text%29%29+%7B%0A%09const+word+%3D+match%5B1%5D%3B%0A%09console.log%28%60Matched+word+with+length+%24%7B+word.length+%7D%3A+%24%7B+word+%7D%60%29%3B%0A%7D&unicodePropertyEscape=1):

```
/((?:[0-9A-Z_a-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1\u05C2\u05C4\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06E1-\u06E8\u06DF-\u06E4\u06ED-\u06F9\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u08D4-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56\u0B57\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C00-\u0C03\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D01-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D57\u0D5F-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0DF2\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB9\u0EBB-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180D\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1AB0-\u1ABE\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CF6\u1CF8\u1CF9\u1D00-\u1DF5\u1DFB-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u200C\u200D\u203F\u2040\u2054\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u24B6-\u24E9\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u2E2F\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u302F\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u3099\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA672\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C5\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABEA\uABEC\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\uFE33\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDD40-\uDD74\uDDFD\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDEE0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF4A\uDF50-\uDF7A\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF\uDFD1-\uDFD5]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE\uDDBF\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05\uDE06\uDE0C-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE3F\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE6\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2]|\uD804[\uDC00-\uDC46\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC82-\uDCBA\uDC7F-\uDC82\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD00-\uDD34\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD73\uDD76\uDD80-\uDDC4\uDDCA-\uDDCC\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE37\uDE3E\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEEA\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF00-\uDF03\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3C-\uDF44\uDF47\uDF48\uDF4B-\uDF4D\uDF50\uDF57\uDF5D-\uDF63\uDF66-\uDF6C\uDF70-\uDF74]|\uD805[\uDC00-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC80-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDB5\uDDB8-\uDDC0\uDDD8-\uDDDD\uDE00-\uDE40\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEB7\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF19\uDF1D-\uDF2B\uDF30-\uDF39]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC36\uDC38-\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F\uDC92-\uDCA7\uDCA9-\uDCB6]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]|\uD809[\uDC00-\uDC6E\uDC80-\uDD43]|[\uD80C\uD81C-\uD820\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDEF0-\uDEF4\uDF00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50-\uDF7E\uDF8F-\uDF9F\uDFE0]|\uD821[\uDC00-\uDFEC]|\uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]|\uD82C[\uDC00\uDC01]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99\uDC9D\uDC9E]|\uD834[\uDD65-\uDD69\uDD6D-\uDD72\uDD7B-\uDD82\uDD85-\uDD8B\uDDAA-\uDDAD\uDE42-\uDE44]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]|\uD836[\uDE00-\uDE36\uDE3B-\uDE6C\uDE75\uDE84\uDE9B-\uDE9F\uDEA1-\uDEAF]|\uD838[\uDC00-\uDC06\uDC08-\uDC18\uDC1B-\uDC21\uDC23\uDC24\uDC26-\uDC2A]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDCD0-\uDCD6\uDD00-\uDD4A\uDD50-\uDD59]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|\uD83C[\uDD30-\uDD49\uDD50-\uDD69\uDD70-\uDD89]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]|\uDB40[\uDD00-\uDDEF])+)/g;
```

Comment: This is cute `[\uD80C\uD81C-\uD820\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C\uD86F-\uD872] [\uDC00-\uDFFF] `. Did you really rescan for low sur's for dup high's ? Not sure this will result in a performance increase in actual usage.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, both of you gave a quite useful explanation.

Comment: @sln The transpiler uses a project of mine named [Regenerate](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate) internally which produces the most optimal/compact non-ASCII output, indeed. Glad you can appreciate it!

Comment: @MathiasBynens - I've had some experience.